Facing issue while pushing index.html file to git
I'm unable to push the index.html file in my React TypeScript application, to Git.
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/" />
    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
            <meta name="description" content="%REACT_APP_PRODUCT_NAME%" />
    
            <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://assets.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.css" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/convo.png" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/convo.png" />
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" 
    href="%PUBLIC_URL%/convo192.png" />
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" 
    href="%PUBLIC_URL%/convo512.png" />
            <title>%REACT_APP_PRODUCT_NAME%</title>
            <script>
                (function(o,r,b,i,t,a,l){
                    o[r]||(t=o[r]=function(){i.push(arguments)},t._t=new Date,t._v=1,i=t._q=[])
                    })(window,'orbital');
                </script>
                <script src="https://client.useorbital.com/api/account/EM3RY6uKy2j7/client.js" async></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app1.</noscript>
            <div id="root"></div>
            <script
                src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
                async
                defer
            >
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>

I was trying to push this index.html file to Git but getting the following error:

Git: RPC failed; HTTP 302 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 302

I have also noticed that if I push without <script> in <head> (where function orbital is defined) then it is getting pushed.
But when I add this <script> and push my changes, it is giving me the error I mentioned above.
import {
    Dialog,
    DialogTitle,
    IconButton,
    DialogContent,
    DialogActions,
    FormGroup,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { joiResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/joi';
import { creditLimitTypes } from '../../config/common.constants';
import TextField from '../common/TextField';
import Select from '../common/Select';
import FormHelperText from '../common/FormHelperText';
import FormLabel from '../common/FormLabel';
import TextButton from '../common/TextButton';
import { CreditGroupDetail, CreditLimitType, CreditPlan } from '../../types';
import { creditGroupSchema } from '../../validation/credit-group-schema';

export interface AddCreditGroupDialogProps {
    open: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
    onSave: (data: CreditGroupDetail) => void;
    creditPlans: CreditPlan[];
}

const AddCreditGroupDialog: React.FC<AddCreditGroupDialogProps> = ({
    open,
    onClose,
    onSave,
    creditPlans,
}) => {
    const [creditPlan, setCreditPlan] = useState<CreditPlan | null>(null);
    const [creditMinLimitType, setCreditMinLimitType] = useState<CreditLimitType | null>(null);
    const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm<CreditGroupDetail>({
        defaultValues: {
            name: '',
            creditPlanId: '',
            minsType: '',
            billingCode: '',
            status: 'active',
        },
        mode: 'onSubmit',
        resolver: joiResolver(creditGroupSchema),
    });

    const handleCreditGroupSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
        onSave({ ...data, status: 'active' });
    });

    return (
        <Dialog
            id="view-customer-group-dialog"
            fullWidth
            maxWidth="md"
            disableBackdropClick
            disableEscapeKeyDown
            open={open}
            onClose={onClose}
        >
            <DialogTitle id="view-customer-credit-group-dialog-title">
                Create Credit Group
                <IconButton
                    id="view-customer-credit-group-dialog-icon-btn"
                    onClick={onClose}
                    style={{ float: 'right' }}
                >
                    <i className="material-icons">close</i>
                </IconButton>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent id="view-customer-credit-group-dialog-content">
                <form name="creditGroupForm" onSubmit={handleCreditGroupSubmit}>
                    <TextField
                        label="Name"
                        fullWidth
                        name="name"
                        inputRef={register}
                        error={!!errors.name}
                        helperText={errors.name?.message}
                        required
                    />
                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormLabel>Credit Plan*</FormLabel>
                        <Select
                            options={creditPlans}
                            value={creditPlan}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                            getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
                            name="creditPlanId"
                            inputRef={register}
                            onChange={setCreditPlan}
                        />
                        <FormHelperText>{errors.creditPlanId?.message}</FormHelperText>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormLabel>Credit Limit Type*</FormLabel>
                        <Select
                            options={creditLimitTypes}
                            value={creditMinLimitType}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                            getOptionValue={(option) => option.value}
                            name="minsType"
                            inputRef={register}
                            onChange={setCreditMinLimitType}
                        />
                        <FormHelperText>{errors.minsType?.message}</FormHelperText>
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormLabel>Billing Code</FormLabel>
                        <TextField name="billingCode" fullWidth inputRef={register} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <DialogActions id="view-customer-credit-group-dialog-actions">
                        <TextButton
                            id="view-customer-credit-group-close-btn"
                            onClick={onClose}
                            color="primary"
                        >
                            Close
                        </TextButton>
                        <TextButton
                            id="view-customer-credit-group-create-btn"
                            type="submit"
                            color="primary"
                        >
                            Create
                        </TextButton>
                    </DialogActions>
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default AddCreditGroupDialog;


I found this article, which might be helpful. Check it out and let me know if it works.
